# KANNEL SMPP not able to send message to geturl

Tags: smpp, kannel

We are not able to receive MO on smpp kannel

below if the configure smsbox configuration

```
group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = 13013
sms-length = 500
smsbox-id = mysmsc

group = sendsms-user
username = tester
password = foobar
#max-messages=3
# http://kannel.machine:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar

group = sms-service
accepted-smsc = smsc2
keyword = default
catch-all = yes
max-messages = 3
get-url = "http://some.com/rcv.php?sender=%p&text=%a"

group = smsbox-route
smsbox-id = mysmsc
smsc-id = smsc2
shortcode = 4867
```

below is the debug log

```
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   validity_period: NULL
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   registered_delivery: 0 = 0x00000000
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   replace_if_present_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   data_coding: 0 = 0x00000000
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   sm_default_msg_id: 0 = 0x00000000
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   sm_length: 4 = 0x00000004
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   short_message: "Test"
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] WARNING: smsbox_list empty!
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[smsc1]: Sending PDU:
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x7f6310005730 dump:
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   type_name: deliver_sm_resp
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483653 = 0x80000005
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [4] WARNING: smsbox_list empty!
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 118 = 0x00000076
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG:   message_id: NULL
2016-08-29 22:22:47 [9639] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an smsc group there (smsc2 is not defined)